# Passing data between fragment using navigation UI component

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I want to pass data between fragments, I have a CharactersFragment and a CharacterDetailFragment, in CharactersFragment I have a recycler view and when I click a item/row, the character details should be sent to ChracterDetailFragment.

I am using navigation UI component, and I am at the moment passing only character name as string.

I have a character object, can I pass character object through safeargs, I read that it is not a right approach.

should I just pass id of the character to the other fragment and retrieve data for that id in the detail fragment?

what is the best approach to solve this please.

Here is the code I have written so far

Thank you very much in advance
R

nav_graph

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/charactersFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/charactersFragment"
        android:name="com.example.breakingbad.CharactersFragment"
        android:label="fragment_characters"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_characters" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_charactersFragment_to_characterDetailFragment"
            app:destination="@id/characterDetailFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/characterDetailFragment"
        android:name="com.example.breakingbad.CharacterDetailFragment"
        android:label="fragment_character_detail"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_character_detail" >
        <argument
            android:name="character"
            app:argType="string" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

CharactersFragment - I have a recyclerview and I am assigning a adapter and passing character name when a row is clicked and navigating to detail screen

```
private fun initView() {
        val recyclerView = binding.recyclerView
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        val decoration = DividerItemDecoration(activity, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL)
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(decoration)

        recyclerAdapter = RecyclerViewAdapter()
        recyclerView.adapter = recyclerAdapter
        recyclerAdapter.onItemClick = { character ->
            val action = CharactersFragmentDirections.actionCharactersFragmentToCharacterDetailFragment(character.name)
            findNavController().navigate(action)
        }
    }
```

RecyclerViewAdapter

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    var items = ArrayList<Character>()
    var onItemClick: ((Character) -> Unit)?  = null
    var itemPosition = 0

    fun setUpdatedData(items: ArrayList<Character>) {
        this.items = items
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.characters_row, parent, false)

        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        itemPosition = position
        holder.bind(items.get(position))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    inner class MyViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val tvName = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvName)

        init {
            view.setOnClickListener {
                Log.d("adapter", "item clicked")
                onItemClick?.invoke(items[this.layoutPosition])
            }
        }

        fun bind(data: Character) {
            tvName.text = data.name
        }
    }
}
```

CharacterDetailFragment

```
class CharacterDetailFragment : Fragment() {

    val args: CharacterDetailFragmentArgs by navArgs()

    private var _binding: FragmentCharacterDetailBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentCharacterDetailBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = binding.root

        binding.tvNumber.text = args.character.toString()
        return view
    }
}
```

Character for ref

```
data class Character(
    val name: String,
    val img: String,
    val occupation: ArrayList<String>,
    val status: String,
    val nickname: String,
    val appearance: ArrayList<Int>
)
```

Thanks
R

Comment: Bundles and intents are not working for me so the ViewModelProvider is the better option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70135731/passing-data-through-navigation-between-fragments-android-studio/78214917#78214917.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either way . Both approaches are fine . But since you are passing only one object or want to have only one object in the next Fragment , you should go for safe args pattern . The reason is there will be an overhead added if you just pass the id and then that id will fetch the data . So to remove that it is preferable to use safe args . Also it is easy to maintain the safeArgs process since it most of the time saves your data on activity / fragment being in the background unlike the other wherein you need to call the api / database again . But if your are getting a list of objects based on the id , then you should do it using the passing the id and getting the data from api/database way .

Since you have no where mentioned in your post of getting a list of Data , below is the way of doing it using SafeArgs.

**Step 1:**  Make your data class Parcelable :

```
@Parcelize
data class Character(
    val name: String,
    val img: String,
    val occupation: ArrayList<String>,
    val status: String,
    val nickname: String,
    val appearance: ArrayList<Int>
):Parcelable
```

**Step 2** : Then in your nav graph you declare an parcelable object to be send to the next fragment as an argument in the nav graph the following way. Select the type as Custom Parcelable and then select your class and also name it as character for better readability in the future .

[image]

Don't forget to add the type of passed object in navigation file

```
<argument
    android:name="character"
    app:argType="com.example.model.WhatEverObject" />
```

**Step 3 :** Now in your fragment , get the data class you want to send and pass it in when you are navigating to the next Fragment .

```
 val action = SenderFragmentDirections.senderFragmentoRecieverFragment(character )
findNavController().navigate(action)
```

**Step 4 :** In the fragment that you are trying to get the args declare a top variable as follows and then in your onCreate() / onViewCreated() get the data .

```
    private val args by navArgs<ReceiverFragmentArgs>()

  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
  args.character.whatever 
//And do your further needs     
}
```

**Remember to setup dependencies correctly in gradle (both app as well as project level)**