# Unresolved reference: Parcelable Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable

I want to use safeArgs to send an object from a fragment to another one but Parcelable is not working even with me adding the necessary plugin. Can somebody please help me?
**the model class**

```
import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize

@Parcelize
data class GazModel(
    val id: String,
    val name: String,
    val description: String?,
    val price : Double,
    val priority: Int,
    val weight : Double,
    val imageUrl : String?,
    var quantity : Int = 0,
    var selected: Boolean = false,
    val gazType: String, // TRADEX, TOTAL, CAMGAZ
) :  Parcelable{}
```

**build.gradle.kts (Project)**

```
 dependencies {
        //...
        val nav_version = "2.3.5"
        classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version")
    }
```

**build.gradle.kts (Module)**

```
plugins {
 //...
    id("androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin")
    id ("kotlin-parcelize")
}
```

**the problem that appear in the problem box**

```
Unresolved reference: os
No 'Parcelable' supertype
Unresolved reference: Parcelable
```

Comment: Are you gradle files Kotlin or Groovy? build.gradle.kts or build.gradle?

Comment: This might help in the futher process : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68973416/passing-data-between-fragment-using-navigation-ui-component/68974089#68974089

Comment: @user2836202, they are build.gradle.kts

Comment: @KaruneshPalekar thank you for the answer sir but i always got the same problem, the parcelable in the data classe is not recognized

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@Parcelize
data class GazModel(
    val id: String,
    val name: String,
    val description: String?,
    val price : Double,
    val priority: Int,
    val weight : Double,
    val imageUrl : String?,
    var quantity : Int = 0,
    var selected: Boolean = false,
    val gazType: String, // TRADEX, TOTAL, CAMGAZ
) :  Parcelable
```

I mean extend with Parcelable not Parcelable{}
Hope this fixes the issue

Comment: This was the issue for me. I simply forgot to add  `: Parcelable` to my data class definition

Answer (score 0):

In the build.gradle (Module), add an id('kotlin-android-extensions') instead of the id ("kotlin-parcelize"), just it !

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

Comment: i tried it but it is not working, and i read id 'kotlin-android-extensions' was deprecated

Comment: Also add this line to build.gradle.kts (Project)
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"